# Expectation derivation

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, expected-value

I have seen this definition of expectation of a nonnegative random variable in many places. I do not quite understand how it is gotten.

$$E[X]=\int_0^{\infty}P(X>t) dt $$

I know $E[X]=\int_0^{\infty}x f(x) dx $

This is used to prove the basic version of markov inequality

Comment: The easiest way to get that equality tho, which is likely shown on prior stackexchange pages, is Fubini-Tonelli $$X = \int_{0}^{\infty} 1_{\{X >t\}}dt \implies E[X] = \int_0^{\infty} E[1_{\{X>t\}}]dt$$ where $1_{\{X>t\}}$ is an indicator function that is $1$ if $\{X>t\}$, and $0$ else.

Comment: Another way to get there using your formula $E[X] = \int_0^{\infty} xf_X(x)dx$ is to use integration by parts with $u=-x, du=-dx$, $dv = -f_X(x)dx$, $v=1-F_X(x)$.

Comment: This is a consequence of Fubini's theorem

Comment: From now on please see 'Related' on the right pane. .